# Keep Masterlist of Objects in Array, check array if it exists before adding a new object

Tags: arrays, object, search

The code below doesn't work as intended to. It never checks for the server in the master list. Am I doing something wrong?

```
var servers = [];
$.serverlist.addServers = function(jsonData) {
for (var server in servers) {
    if (server["ID"] == jsonData["ID"]) {
        // server exists, dont add, just update
    } else {
        //server doesnt exist, just add it
    }
}
```

The `jsonData` I'm receiving is formatted like so:

```
{ "ID": 1, "something else": "Value", "another key": "Key Val" }
```

So when it goes into the array, the array states (if there were multiple added)

```
[
 0:
   {
    "ID":1,
    "something else": "Value",
    "another key": "Key Val"
   }
  1: 
   {
    "ID":2,etc...
   } 
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try testing the array length.

```
if( servers.length > 0 ){
    // Server exist!
    console.log("Append!");
}else{
    // Doesn't...
    console.log("Create the array.");
}
```

**EDIT**

For a specific object, this should do:

```
if( servers.indexOf(jsonData["ID"]) != -1 ){
    // Data is in array
    console.log("It's there.");
}else{
    // Doesn't...
    console.log("It's not there.");
}
```

**2nd EDIT**

I made a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/wWjbRo?editors=1111) of what it should look like.
But I'm not sure about your data... It looks like DOM object format when you console log it.
I think it's different than a json or an object...

I made my example based on an array of objects.
Look at CodePen console.

```
var servers = [
  {
    "ID":1,
    "something else": "Value",
    "another key": "Key Val"
   },
  {
    "ID":2,
    "something else": "another Value",
    "another key": "another Key Val"
   },
  {
    "ID":3,
    "something else": "Boring Value",
    "another key": "Interesting!"
   },
  {
    "ID":4,
    "something else": "arrggg.",
    "another key": "Yeah!"
   } 
];

for(i=0;i<servers.length;i++){
  var temp = servers[i];
  if (temp.ID== 3){
    console.log("Found!");
    break;                  // Exits the loop when found ID = 3
  }else{
    console.log("NOT fount yet... Still checking.");
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd do that but I'll be dealing with with a lot of objects in the server array, and I need to find one with the same id, as they are all unique.

Comment: You should show how your array is structured for more specific answer... ;)

Comment: Closer haha! I guess my post was not clear. The jsonData I'm receiving is formatted as such.
{
  "ID": 1,
  "something else": "Value",
  "another key": "Key Val"
}

So when it goes into the array, the array states [if there were multiple added]
    [
      0:
        {"ID":1,"something else": "Value","another key": "Key Val"}
      2:
        {"ID":2,etc...}
    ]

Comment: Didn't see that button initially. Added.